# How to convert IST time stored as string into Sql Server DateTime Data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Varchar data type in my Sql Server table.
It is used for saving Date and time in IST as string.

```
For e.g Sat Sep 01 2012 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Can any one please help me in converting this string into Sql Server Datetime Type, using sql query.

Comment: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @dt varchar(50)='Sat Sep 01 2012 09:00:00 GMT+0530'
select CONVERT(datetime,substring(@dt,5,20))
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6063)